# Ansible : Switch to a user and display its name

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I have two users under my remote host server : **firas , michel**

In my playbook , i'm connectiong  as **"firas"** and am trying to execute some task with **"michel"** user

(therefore , to just assert it , i'm trying to display the user who is running the task in each time").

**My host file looks like this :**

```
[myHost]
server1

[myHost:vars]
ansible_user=firas
```

**My tasks are the following :**

```
- name: switch to user michel and run whoami
  shell: whoami
  remote_user: michel 
  register: username_michel 
  when:
    - ansible_host in groups['myHost']

- debug:
   msg: "user supposed to be michel is ; {{username_michel.stdout}}"
  when:
    - ansible_host in groups['myHost']

- name: switch to user firas and run whoami
  shell: whoami
  remote_user: firas
  register: username_firas
  when:
    - ansible_host in groups['myHost']

- debug:
   msg: "user supposed to be adi is ; {{username_firas.stdout}}"
  when:
    - ansible_host in groups['myHost']
```

**->** but the strange that , like this : i obtain always the user *"firas"* as the active user

And seems that switching user is not running

**any ideas?**

Comment: What is the question? Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection variable you defined in the inventory `ansible_user=firas` has precedence over `remote_user: michel` declaration in the task. Remove it.

Per explanation in [Possible Misunderstanding](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/20045#issuecomment-271336150):

> As documented http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable, the connection variables have precedence over directives, this is done as host connection information is considered more 'specific' than play connection information. You can still override this from the play by setting the connection variable (as you would any variable).

Comment: remove what exactly ? , therfore i need to connect with that user , and switch to another is some tasks

Comment: "*It*" refers to the subject of the first sentence: "***The connection variable** you defined in the inventory `ansible_user=firas`*".

Comment: cannot do it , because i need it to establish the first connextion , unless it throws me some error of not beeing able to connect

Comment: Use `remote_user` in the play (which you did not even post, have you read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))? Or just configure your SSH client to use `firas` user.